# Need to average values for usernames in 2 territories

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to display a report with averages. Unfortunately, averages don't work out when a null is found. And Null does = 0, Null means not present.....

[image]

I created a sample table to illustrate the issue.
I am trying to avoid making a long case statement to determine if the fields have values > 0

```
-- The purpose of the report is to show sales per user name regardless of territory
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Sales', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Sales;                              

    CREATE TABLE #Sales
        (
          [Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
          [UserName] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
          [Territory] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
          [Sales] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL ,
          [HoursWorked] [INT] NULL ,
          [DaysOff]  [INT] NULL 
        );

INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Pete Brown', 'PBrown', 'South',11.62790698, 200,NULL)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Pete Brown', 'PBrown', 'North',5.56423578,40,10)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Walter Harvey', 'WHarvey', 'South',44.24648647,NULL,80)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Walter Harvey', 'WHarvey', 'North',NULL,40,60)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Donna Gibson', 'DGibson', 'South',8.56243212,NULL,50)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Donna Gibson', 'DGibson', 'North',NULL,40,40)


INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Jack Rusell', 'JRusell', 'South',NULL,60,40)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Steve Black', 'SBlack', 'South',NULL,80,80)
INSERT INTO #Sales ( Name, UserName, Territory, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff ) VALUES  ( 'Troy Peters', 'TPeters', 'South',8.54623512,10,10)

-- Check sample inserts
SELECT * FROM #Sales ORDER BY UserName

-- The report will now identify which users have more than one territory
IF object_id('tempdb..#DualTerritoryAgents') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DualTerritoryAgents;
      SELECT r1.* 
      INTO #DualTerritoryAgents
      FROM #Sales r1
      JOIN  #Sales r2 ON r2.username = r1.username
      WHERE r1.Territory = 'North' AND r2.Territory = 'South'

-- Show dual territory agents
SELECT * FROM #DualTerritoryAgents

-- Final report with averages (do not include territory, average sales, average hours worked and average Daysoff)
SELECT Name, UserName, Sales, HoursWorked, DaysOff FROM #Sales
WHERE UserName NOT IN (SELECT UserName FROM #DualTerritoryAgents)
UNION
SELECT  Name, 
        UserName,       
        SUM(Sales) /2, 
        SUM(HoursWorked) /2, 
        SUM(DaysOff) /2
FROM #Sales
WHERE UserName IN (SELECT UserName FROM #DualTerritoryAgents)
GROUP BY Name, UserName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `SUM()`?  Use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT Name, 
       UserName,       
       AVG(Sales), 
       AVG(HoursWorked), 
       AVG(DaysOff)
FROM #Sales
WHERE UserName IN (SELECT UserName FROM #DualTerritoryAgents)
GROUP BY Name, UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `SUM(Sales) /2` with `SUM((CASE Sales is NULL THEN 0 ELSE Sales END) / 2` should make the deal.

Edit.
And obviously same for other fields you calculating.

Comment: Sorry, Null does not equal 0, Null means not present

Comment: then why wouldn't you filter out null values? like `AND Sales IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I cannot, since other values in the same row are NOT NULL